# MSI GE72 2QC, Xubuntu 16.04, wifi security key not asked

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, network-manager

since several weeks, I cannot connect to wifi network. The icon on top of the screen is working but no security key is asked when I try to connect to ANY wifi network; However when I connect to a wifi network which ask security key  in Firefox it works!....

I tried the command Journalctl -f and the output is

```
enter code Activation: (wifi) access point 'Livebox-0b18' has security, but secrets are required.
    déc. 28 15:57:41 odile-GE72-2QC NetworkManager[1112]:   [1482937061.3672] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
    déc. 28 15:57:41 odile-GE72-2QC gnome-keyring-daemon[1770]: The Secret Service was already initialized
    déc. 28 15:57:41 odile-GE72-2QC org.freedesktop.secrets[2538]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
    déc. 28 15:58:06 odile-GE72-2QC NetworkManager[1112]:   [1482937086.3725] device (wlan0): No agents were available for this request
```

What would be the solution ?

I tried also to restart wpasupplicant and I get :

```
 wpa_supplicant[3276]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
 wpa_supplicant[3276]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
 wpa_supplicant[3276]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
 wpa_supplicant[3276]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlan0 flags: No such device``
```

When I edit the connection, It works!.....

My chipset :

```
*-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.6
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: d5
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:26 mémoire:a3200000-a32fffff
           *-network
                description: Interface réseau sans fil
                produit: Wireless 3160
                fabriquant: Intel Corporation
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
                nom logique: wlan0
                version: 83
                numéro de série: b4:6d:83:d2:05:b9
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.1.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                ressources: irq:33 mémoire:a3200000-a3201fff
```

Comment: Does it work when you edit the connection?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by edit the connection?

Comment: https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-48735853416bffca5b4336cb1d46efe6?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: No it does not work either when I edit the connection

Comment: I meant editing and adding the key. If it still doesn't work either the key is wrong or you really have a problem. This assumes it was working before and you haven't done anything other then installing updates as prompted. Lastly, please update your question with your wireless chipset.

Comment: Yes it does work when I edit the connection. Do you have any suggestion on what to do to make it work withour editing the connection,  like it used to work.

Comment: No, not really. I had the same twice and it seemed to be solved by some update once and a release upgrade in the other.